# Download Ubuntu daily ISOs and make them into VMs for alpha and beta testing

Tags: beginner, bash, installer

I'm an Ubuntu contributor, and I finally got tired of the workflow for ISO testing I was using (zsync, gpg, sha256sum, create Gnome Boxes VM, install, delete VM). So I decided to make a Bash script to automate a bunch of the process for me.

Trouble is, Bash is not my "native" programming language. The code works properly in my testing, but it looks like something died in the explosion.

In addition to suggestions to clean up the code, I'd be interested in knowing what techniques I can use to avoid writing such messy code in the future. This is my third major Bash script I've written, and all three looked pretty bad, so anything I can do to avoid that in the future would be helpful.

The code is available on my GitHub repository, [ArrayBolt3/vm-isotest](https://github.com/ArrayBolt3/vm-isotest). It has quite a few features, modes, and options, so you will probably want to read the README on GitHub to get a good idea of what all the arguments do. Here's the full script. I'm running it on Ubuntu Studio 22.04, which I believe is using Bash 5.1.

```
#! /bin/bash

# vm-isotest - Automatically zsync and verify ISOs, and build quick testing VMs out of them.

# Checks to see if the virtual disk repo exists, creates it if it doesn't, and throws a fit if something gets in its way.
if [ -e "$HOME/vm-isotest-virtdisks" ] && [ -d "$HOME/vm-isotest-virtdisks" ]; then
    if [ ! -e "$HOME/vm-isotest-virtdisks/vmisotestmark" ]; then
        echo "Fatal error: ~/vm-isotest-virtdisks directory exists and is not marked safe."
        exit
    fi
else
    if [ -e "$HOME/vm-isotest-virtdisks" ]; then
        echo "Fatal error: a file named ~/vm-isotest-virtdisks exists."
        exit
    else
        mkdir "$HOME/vm-isotest-virtdisks"
        echo 0 > "$HOME/vm-isotest-virtdisks/vmisotestmark"
    fi
fi

# Argument parser
initMode=0
finalArgCount=0
getArgValue="no"
hitArgListEnd="no"
cntr=0
params=( "$@" )
while [ $cntr -le $(($# - 1)) ]; do
    arg=${params[$cntr]}
    if [ "$arg" = "-d" ]; then
        if [ $initMode -eq 0 ]; then
            vmmode="d"
            initMode=1
            cntr=$(($cntr + 1))
            continue
        else
            echo "Fatal error: unexpected argument -d"
            exit
        fi
    elif [ "$arg" = "-l" ]; then
        if [ $initMode -eq 0 ]; then
            vmmode="l"
            initMode=1
            cntr=$(($cntr + 1))
            continue
        else
            echo "Fatal error: unexpected argument -l"
            exit
        fi
    elif [ "$arg" = "-b" ]; then
        if [ $initMode -eq 0 ]; then
            vmmode="b"
            initMode=1
            cntr=$(($cntr + 1))
            continue
        else
            echo "Fatal error: unexpected argument -b"
            exit
        fi
    elif [ "$arg" = "-dlonly" ]; then
        if [ $initMode -eq 0 ]; then
            vmmode="dlonly"
            initMode=1
            cntr=$(($cntr + 1))
            continue
        else
            echo "Fatal error: unexpected argument -dlonly"
            exit
        fi
    fi
    if [ "$getArgValue" = "no" ]; then
        hitArgListEnd="yes"
        if [ "$arg" = "-cpus" ]; then
            hitArgListEnd="no"
            getArgValue="cpus"
        elif [ "$arg" = "-m" ]; then
            hitArgListEnd="no"
            getArgValue="m"
        elif [ "$arg" = "-space" ]; then
            hitArgListEnd="no"
            getArgValue="space"
        elif [ "$arg" = "-graphics" ]; then
            hitArgListEnd="no"
            getArgValue="graphics"
        elif [ "$arg" = "-efi" ]; then
            hitArgListEnd="no"
            efiFirmware="yes"
        elif [ "$arg" = "-persist" ]; then
            hitArgListEnd="no"
            persistDisk="yes"
        elif [ "$arg" = "-ramdisk" ]; then
            hitArgListEnd="no"
            useRAMDisk="yes"
        elif [ "$arg" = "-live" ]; then
            hitArgListEnd="no"
            liveTest="yes"
        elif [ "$arg" = "-nodisk" ]; then
            hitArgListEnd="no"
            noDisk="yes"
        fi
    else
        if [ "$getArgValue" = "cpus" ]; then
            numCPUs=$arg
        elif [ "$getArgValue" = "m" ]; then
            ramSize=$arg
        elif [ "$getArgValue" = "space" ]; then
            diskSpace=$arg
        elif [ "$getArgValue" = "graphics" ]; then
            graphicsMode=$arg
        fi
        getArgValue="no"
    fi
    if [ "$hitArgListEnd" = "yes" ]; then
        if [ "$vmmode" = "d" ] || [ "$vmmode" = "dlonly" ]; then
            if [ $cntr -lt $(($# - 3)) ]; then
                echo "Fatal error: unrecognized argument $arg."
                exit
            elif [ $finalArgCount -eq 0 ]; then
                zsyncURL=$arg
            elif [ $finalArgCount -eq 1 ]; then
                gpgURL=$arg
            elif [ $finalArgCount -eq 2 ]; then
                sha256URL=$arg
            fi
            finalArgCount=$(($finalArgCount + 1))
        else
            if [ $cntr -ne $(($# - 1)) ]; then
                echo "Fatal error: unrecognized argument $arg."
                exit
            else
                imgPath=$arg
            fi
        fi
    fi
    cntr=$(($cntr + 1))
done

# Do sanity checks and set defaults
if [ "$vmmode" = "d" ] || [ "$vmmode" = "dlonly" ]; then
    if [ "$zsyncURL" = "" ]; then
        echo "Fatal error: no zsync URL provided."
        exit
    elif [ "$gpgURL" = "" ]; then
        echo "Fatal error: no GPG verification URL provided."
        exit
    elif [ "$sha256URL" = "" ]; then
        echo "Fatal error: no SHA256SUMS URL provided."
        exit
    fi
fi

if [ "$numCPUs" = "" ]; then
    numCPUs=2
fi
if [ "$ramSize" = "" ]; then
    ramSize="4G"
fi
if [ "$diskSpace" = "" ]; then
    if [ "$useRAMDisk" = "yes" ]; then
        diskSpace=15G
    else
        diskSpace=20G
    fi
fi
if [ "$graphicsMode" = "" ]; then
    graphicsMode="qxl"
fi

# zsync the ISO
if [ "$vmmode" = "d" ] || [ "$vmmode" = "dlonly" ]; then
    zsync $zsyncURL
    rm SHA256SUMS
    rm SHA256SUMS.gpg
    wget $gpgURL > /dev/null
    wget $sha256URL > /dev/null
    gpg --keyid-format=long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
    sha256sum -c --ignore-missing SHA256SUMS
    read -n1 -s # Wait for the user to check the results of the download and test before proceeding.
fi

# Create the VM
if [ "$vmmode" = "d" ] || [ "$vmmode" = "l" ]; then
    if [ "$noDisk" != "yes" ]; then
        # Read the counter from the vmisotestmark file, and increment the counter. This counter is used to ensure unique VM disk image names.
        vmNameCounter=`cat ~/vm-isotest-virtdisks/vmisotestmark`
        vmNameCounter=$(($vmNameCounter + 1))
        rm ~/vm-isotest-virtdisks/vmisotestmark
        echo $vmNameCounter > ~/vm-isotest-virtdisks/vmisotestmark

        # Now do the actual VM creation.
        if [ "$useRAMDisk" = "yes" ]; then
            if [ ! -e /dev/shm/vm-isotest/img$vmNameCounter ]; then
                qemu-img create -f qcow2 "/dev/shm/vm-isotest-img$vmNameCounter" $diskSpace
            else
                echo "Fatal error - could not create VM disk image. Attempting to run the command again, unmodified, should work."
                exit
            fi
        else
            if [ ! -e ~/vm-isotest-virtdisks/vm-isotest-img$vmNameCounter ]; then
                qemu-img create -f qcow2 "$HOME/vm-isotest-virtdisks/vm-isotest-img$vmNameCounter" $diskSpace
            else
                echo "Fatal error - could not create VM disk image. Attempting to run the command again, unmodified, should work."
                exit
            fi
        fi
    fi
fi

# Determine ISO name when in d mode
if [ "$vmmode" = "d" ]; then
    zsyncFilename=`echo "$zsyncURL" | cut -f7 -d "/"`
    if [ "$zsyncFilename" = "" ]; then # The plain Ubuntu ISOs have a path with one fewer slashes in it than the Ubuntu flavours' paths, so if the 7th field is empty, we try the 6th instead.
        zsyncFilename=`echo "$zsyncURL" | cut -f6 -d "/"`
    fi
    imgPath=`echo $zsyncFilename | head -c -7 -`
fi

# Launch and clean up the VM
if [ "$vmmode" != "dlonly" ]; then
    qemuCmdline="-enable-kvm -smp $numCPUs -m $ramSize -machine q35 -device qemu-xhci -device usb-tablet -device usb-kbd -device intel-hda -device hda-duplex"
    if [ "$efiFirmware" = "yes" ]; then
        qemuCmdline="$qemuCmdline -bios /usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd"
    fi
    if [ "$graphicsMode" = "qxl" ]; then
        qemuCmdline="$qemuCmdline -vga qxl"
    elif [ "$graphicsMode" = "virgl" ]; then
        qemuCmdline="$qemuCmdline -vga virtio -display gtk,gl=on"
    else # VGA graphics, unaccelerated
        qemuCmdline="$qemuCmdline -vga std"
    fi
    if [ "$vmmode" = "b" ]; then
        qemuInitCmdline="$qemuCmdline -hda $imgPath"
    else
        if [ "$noDisk" = "yes" ]; then
            qemuInitCmdline="$qemuCmdline -cdrom $imgPath"
        else
            if [ "$useRAMDisk" = "yes" ]; then
                qemuInitCmdline="$qemuCmdline -boot dc -cdrom $imgPath -hda /dev/shm/vm-isotest-img$vmNameCounter"
                qemuCmdline="$qemuCmdline -hda /dev/shm/vm-isotest-img$vmNameCounter"
            else
                qemuInitCmdline="$qemuCmdline -boot dc -cdrom $imgPath -hda $HOME/vm-isotest-virtdisks/vm-isotest-img$vmNameCounter"
                qemuCmdline="$qemuCmdline -hda $HOME/vm-isotest-virtdisks/vm-isotest-img$vmNameCounter"
            fi
        fi
    fi
    qemu-system-x86_64 $qemuInitCmdline
    if [ "$liveTest" != "yes" ] && [ "$vmmode" != "b" ]; then
        qemu-system-x86_64 $qemuCmdline
    fi
    if [ "$persistDisk" != "yes" ] && [ "$vmmode" != "b" ] && [ "$noDisk" != "yes" ]; then
        if [ "$useRAMDisk" = "yes" ]; then
            rm "/dev/shm/vm-isotest-img$vmNameCounter"
        else
            rm "$HOME/vm-isotest-virtdisks/vm-isotest-img$vmNameCounter"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is totally clean and readable.  There is nothing to be embarrassed about here.  You've picked sane variable names and consistently followed good indentation.  Nesting the `then`s on the line with the `if`s is good for readability and idiomatic shell.  You're doing better than code I've seen from proprietary software developers writing installers.

## nits

- Check out [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/). It will encourage you to quote your variable substitutions and not use `$` inside of `$(( ))`-style calculations.
- Using `[[ ]]` - double square brackets - instead of single square brackets will help avoid some surprises.
- You can combine your conditionals in one set of brackets.  So `[ "$vmmode" = "d" ] || [ "$vmmode" = "l" ]` becomes `[ "$vmmode" == "d" || "$vmmode" == "l" ]`.  This also shows that using `==` is good for indicating an equality check so that a single equals is clearly an assignment.
- It is a good habit to use `$!/usr/bin/env bash` to support systems that have bash in a non-standard path.

## suggestions

- Most of your code is dealing with arguments.  You will probably find that [getopt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52674277/2002471) will let you do that with less code on your part.
- For code this long I would try to split it up into functions.  As I've noted [elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313501/79839) this is good for readability and gives you variable scoping, if you want it.
- If you want to push your shell ability further, consider reading the [Google Shell Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html).  I don't agree with all of their suggestions, but they explain their reasoning well enough that you can consider what will be beneficial for you.